# jQuery cookies, set dynamic name to the cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs, jquery-cookie

I'm using jQuery tabs with jQuery cookie.

I'm using jQuery cookie to save the current selected tab, my problem is that I'm using a lot o tabs in my project, and once the selected tab is saved in cookie, is being saved for all of the tabs.

**Is there any solution to it?
I was thinking about setting dynamic cookie names for every page? But, how do I do that?**

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
            cookie: {
                expires: 1,
                name: // set different cookie name for each #tabs
 }});​
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: For this kind of info I would use DOM storage, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Answer (score 1):

You can't set name to be callable at this time, but you can change cookie option (or any other option passed to `.tabs` constructor) by using: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-option

Assuming you initialized tabs, for example by using:

```
// intitialization
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    expires: 1, name: 'something'
});
```

Whenever you need to change cookie name you can do:

```
// when you want to change cookie option for that tabs
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "cookie", {expires: 1, name: 'booyah'})
// ... somewhere else in your code, change it again, just for fun
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "cookie", {expires: 1, name: 'grandma'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a cookie `name` seems to work just fine for me:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    cookie:{
        expires: 7,
        path: '/',
        name: '<some variable name>'
    }
});
```